# What's kern_sploit proccess that apears in my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

After jailbreaking iPhone 4, I was noticed that some processes were added to the process list, like `kern_sploit`. What is this?

Answer (score 1):

It's Greenpoison's exploit. It's legit. According to the GitHub source, Snowbreeze [installs it](https://github.com/iH8sn0w/sn0wbreeze/blob/27ac4a6ba9bb6d64ec26e431be6b8fb052047d63/modIPSW.vb#L490).